# if condition breaks code in while loop in Jenkinsfile, writing a script to loop and break until the condition is met

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to implement a feature in a script where it needs to loop forever when the variable's condition is true. The code simply does not get executed in jenkins and it gets skipped for some reason

```
statz build = 'checking the output'
//if output is running then loop until its running
    while [[ $statz_build = 'running' ]]
    do 
       echo 'runnig while loop'
       statz_build= 'checking the condition'
       if [[ $statz_build != 'running' ]]; then
       break
   fi
   done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple syntax issues with your script. Among others:

1. `//` is not a valid comment character in Bash. Use `#`.
2. `statz_build= 'checking the condition'` is not a valid assignment. Bash requires the absence of whitespace around the assignment operator, e.g. `statz_build='checking the condition'`.
3. The posted code *never* assigns "running" to *statz_build*, so your condition will never be true.
4. Your while-loop starts out false, so it will never execute. Use `until` instead.

You may have other logic or syntax issues as well. You should use shellcheck or a debugger to validate your code.